# How to read the first 3 three-digit numbers from a text file?

Tags: java

I'd like to add 3 three-digit numbers to a list in every line.

I have tried to create a count, but I couldn't do it well.

```
int i = 0;
try (Scanner s = new Scanner("final.txt")))  {
    String line;
    while (s.hasNextLine()) {
        int change2Int = s.nextInt();
        s.nextLine(); // ignore the rest of the line
        figures [i] = change2Int;
        i++;
    }
}
```

}

So I have a txt file with about 20 lines. A line looks like this: (the firt block is FROM: hour, minute, second. || the second is TO: hour, minute, second. || and the last is: phone number |

Here is a line from the txt file:
"6 1 0 6 2 25 392712621"

I'd like to add the first three numbers (the first three means: "from hour(6) minute (1) second (0)

next 3 means "To: hour(6) minute (2) second(25)

and 392712621 is the phone number.

I'd like to add the first 3 number to a list and the next 3 to an other list.
And do it with every line.

How could I do this?

Comment: Split on spaces, convert to integers

Comment: Read one line at a time and use String.split() and then pick the numbers you want from the array returned by the split method

Comment: Would `6 1 0 6 2 25` be stored as a sum in the list or just a String?Can you share a sample output?

Comment: Can you make assumptions about the encoding of the file?

Comment: And what do you want to do with the 3 number list, add it to another list or just continue to add all from numbers to one list and all to numbers to another list?

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression with three grouping operations. Group three digital sequences, then three digital sequences, then a final sequence. Test if the input matches the pattern, and then pull out the three groups. Like,

```
String s = "6 1 0 6 2 25 392712621";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+ \\d+ \\d+) (\\d+ \\d+ \\d+) (\\d+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
if (m.matches()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1).trim());
    System.out.println(m.group(2).trim());
    System.out.println(m.group(3).trim());
}
```

And I get (as requested)

```
6 1 0
6 2 25
392712621
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick,

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("final.txt"));

        List<String> firstList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> secondList = new ArrayList<>();

        while (s.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = s.nextLine();
            String[] digits = line.split(" ");
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                firstList.add(digits[i]);
            }
            for (int i = 3; i < 6; i++) {
                secondList.add(digits[i]);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(firstList);
        System.out.println(secondList);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd suggest reading the file as follows:

```
try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get("final.txt"))) {
     ...
} catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
```

as it will make your life much easier:

Second, I would not maintain two lists of related data, rather I'd create a model to represent it:

```
class HourModel {          
    public HourModel(LocalTime from, LocalTime to) {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
    }

    private LocalTime from;
    private LocalTime to;
}
```

Not the most meaningful name but I've called it `HourModel` for examples purposes only. I'd expect you to rename it to make it more meaningful.

Finally, you can get the result you're after with:

```
List<HourModel> hourModels;
try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get("final.txt"))) {
      hourModels = stream.map(line -> {
          String[] numbers = line.split(" ");
          LocalTime from = LocalTime.of(Integer.parseInt(numbers[0]),Integer.parseInt(numbers[1]),Integer.parseInt(numbers[2]));
          LocalTime to = LocalTime.of(Integer.parseInt(numbers[3]),Integer.parseInt(numbers[4]),Integer.parseInt(numbers[5]));
          return new HourModel(from , to);
  }).collect(Collectors.toList());    
} catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
```

Note, that I've used `LocaleTime` to represent the `hour` , `minute` and `second` simply because it's the better way to represent it.

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case using `Scanner` is not optimal (but you can if you want). I offer use Java8 feature and `Stream` to read text file line by line.

And us RegExp with named group that represent each line.

As result, you could use `LocalTime`.

```
public static void readFile(Path path, List<LocalTime> from, List<LocalTime> to) throws IOException {
    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<fromHour>\\d+)\\s+(?<fromMinute>\\d+)\\s+(?<fromSecond>\\d+)\\s+" +
            "(?<toHour>\\d+)\\s+(?<toMinute>\\d+)\\s+(?<toSecond>\\d+)\\s+(?<data>\\d+)");

    Files.lines(path)
         .map(pattern::matcher)
         .filter(Matcher::matches)
         .forEach(matcher -> {
             from.add(localTime(matcher, "fromHour", "fromMinute", "fromSecond"));
             to.add(localTime(matcher, "toHour", "toMinute", "toSecond"));
         });
}

private static LocalTime localTime(Matcher matcher, String hour, String minute, String second) {
    int fromHour = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(hour));
    int fromMinute = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(minute));
    int fromSecond = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(second));
    return LocalTime.of(fromHour, fromMinute, fromSecond);
}
```